# Extjs - advanced Search Form

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc, advanced-search

I need to build an advanced search form using Extjs 4 but I am not sure from where to start. I searched a lot through internet but I haven't found a clear way to do it or even a good example. can anyone help me?

**EDIT**
It's a form with many text fields as criterias, which user can enter at least one search criteria to do a search and get the result related to what he typed.

**Edit 2** *hopefully better description of the goals*

I need a separate filter panel with one filter per line. A filter is build of two combo boxes: *Field-Select* and *Condition-Select* and at least the value which may be text, numeric, date, ...

Below the last filterline will be a plus button/combo to add a new Filter

Comment: How do you define a advanced search form?  Please rephrase your question.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking for. A (code)example might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you sra. I need to accomplish something like this http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?59137-Flexible-multi-line-Grid-Dataview-whatever-filtering but simpler

Comment: Now I understand what you are looking for. I will need this in further  but slightly more complex and have already looked where I could start. Well, see my post.

Answer (score 2):

Now I understand what you are looking for. The nearest already implemented solution for that:  **[Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature)** *(and this one is also much less complex)*. Per default it only publish it self as Column-Menu and I haven't found a implementation like

[image]

Anyway, this feature will be best point for you start if it not already fit your needs. Extend it with a view like above. Best thing is that it is already providing separate Filtertypes which makes it easy extensible later on.

You may also give it a try to port your example solution to ExtJS4 but I would recommend you stay with a supported one that you simply extend.

Comment: sorry for the delay, can you tell me where can I get this kind of dynamic filter for extjs? (like the image you posted here) thanks!

Comment: @SexyMF This image is taken from [this post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?59137-Flexible-multi-line-Grid-Dataview-whatever-filtering)

Comment: Thanks for replying (-: is this will work with version 4.2? thanks again!

Comment: @SexyMF I doubt that it will work with 4.x But you may use the Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature to start your own component as suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a tree panel at ur left which cntains search criteras, on which u wanna search, keep a centr panel inwhich on clik of node here it cms fr search aftr search replace centr panl with search results

Comment: Thanks .. do you have an example explains that ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a grid, combobox or some other source to search in? These Ext components have a **store** where you can **filter** data.

[Combobox autocomplete](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/form/combos.html) OR [Grid column filtering](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html).

If you need something else let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. the links are very useful but I also need something like this but simpler and work for Extjs 4.1  http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?59137-Flexible-multi-line-Grid-Dataview-whatever-filtering